# [undefined-reference][lnk2019] -> [unresolved-external]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The tag [undefined-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-reference) seems to be another name for [unresolved-external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unresolved-external) (it seems that both phrases match particular compilers' error messages and users select what they see).

[lnk2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lnk2019) seems to be another synonym, based on one compiler's error code.  It certainly doesn't make sense out of context!

Can we merge these three tags into a single [unresolved-external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unresolved-external) tag?